# C# : how to create delegate type from delegate types?

Tags: c#, delegates

In C#, how does one create a delegate type that maps delegate types to a delegate type?
In particular, in my example below, I want to declare a delegate `Sum` such that (borrowing from mathematical notation) `Sum(f,g) = f + g`.  I then want to invoke `Sum(f,g)` -- such as `Sum(f,g)(5)` [this meaning `f(5) + g(5)`].

```
class  Example
{
delegate  int  IntToInt  ( int i ) ;

public static int Double ( int i )  { return i * 2 ; }
public static int Square ( int i )  { return i * i ; }

delegate  IntToInt  IntToIntPair_To_IntToInt  ( IntToInt f, IntToInt g ) ;

public static IntToInt Sum ( IntToInt f, IntToInt, g )  { return f + g ; }

public static void Main ( )
    {
    IntToInt  DoubleInstance  =  Double ;
    IntToInt  SquareInstance  =  Square ;

    IntToIntPair_To_IntToInt  SumInstance  =  Sum ;

    System.Console.WriteLine
          ( SumInstance ( DoubleInstance, SquareInstance ) ( 5 ) ) ;
    // should print 35 = 10 + 25 = Double(5) + Square(5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to express the specific types. For example:

```
Func<Func<int, int>, Func<int, int>>
```

represents a function which takes a (function converting an int to a second int) and returns a (function converting an int to a second int). Or to take two functions and return a third:

```
Func<Func<int, int>, Func<int, int>, Func<int, int>>
```

For example:

```
Func<Func<int, int>, Func<int, int>> applyTwice = (f => x => f(f(x));
```

This can be returned generically by a method:

```
public static Func<Func<T,T>, Func<T,T>> ApplyTwice<T>()
{
    return func => x => func(func(x));
}
```

If you want to sum two functions, you might do:

```
public static Func<int, int> Sum(Func<int, int> first, Func<int, int> second)
{
    return x => first(x) + second(x);
}
```

Now to apply it:

```
Func<int, int> doubler = x => x * 2;
Func<int, int> squarer = x => x * x;
Func<int, int> doublePlusSquare = Sum(doubler, squarer);

Console.WriteLine(doublePlusSquare(5)); // Prints 35
```

(Untested, but should be okay...)

---

If you don't have C# 3 and .NET 3.5 available to you, then declare the following delegates:

```
public delegate TResult Func<TResult>();
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg);
public delegate TResult Func<T1, T2, TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
```

(There's more on my [C# Versions page](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx).)

Then you'll need to use anonymous methods, e.g.

```
public static Func<int, int> Sum(Func<int, int> first, Func<int, int> second)
{
    return delegate(int x) { return first(x) + second(x); };
}

Func<int, int> doubler = delegate (int x) { return x * 2; };
Func<int, int> squarer = delegate (int x) { return x * x; };
Func<int, int> doublePlusSquare = Sum(doubler, squarer);

Console.WriteLine(doublePlusSquare(5)); // Prints 35
```

Comment: Dammit, you get one sentence off an answer and bam, skeeted again.

Comment: Jon:  My software is somewhat dated.  Does it matter that I'm using CLR Version 2.0.50727.42 ?

Comment: @JaysonFix: Yes, unfortunately, the lambda syntax (x=>x*2 for example) and the Func<T> delegate types are C#3/.NET3.5 constructs. To do this in .NET2.0 and C#2 will take more effort.

Comment: You will need to declare your own IntToInt and IntFuncToIntFunc types so that you can do something similar.

Comment: Jeff:  Unfortunately, I'm using C#2.

Comment: Jon:  I'm getting a compiler-error: error CS1661: Cannot convert anonymous method block to delegate type 'Example.Func<Example.Func<int,int>,Example.Func<int,int>,Example.Func<int,int>>' because the specified block's parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types

Comment: (You say you're using C#2 and CLR 2.0.5.... etc.)  Note that C# 2.0 and 3.5 both run on the same CLR version, so you can use C# 3.5 in an old project - you just can't use the new library types.  In short, if you have a new compiler, you _can_ use the simpler lambda notation and type inference options, you'll just need to declare Func<> yourself.

Comment: Summary: if possible, try to upgrade to use C# 3.5, and simply link to the old library versions for the best of both worlds: simpler syntax and backwards compatibility.

Comment: public static Func<Func<int, int>, Func<int, int>, Func<int, int>> Sum(Func<int, int> first, Func<int, int> second)
{
    return x => first(x) + second(x);
}

should only return Func<int, int> because that's the type of doublePlusSquare.

Comment: I am still learning, so I verified your comments "(Untested, but should be okay...)" :-).

Alternatively, you could use 

Console.WriteLine(doublePlusSquare (doubler, squarer).Invoke(5));

That should work too.

Comment: squarer = delegate { int x }
should be
squarer = delegate ( int x )
Otherwise, works well for me.
Thanks Jon and everyone!

Comment: Darn it. I really should try to post on a machine where I can test this stuff easily :)

Comment: One small thing:  it seems the line reading 
"public delegate TResult Func<TResult>();"
 can be omitted from the C#2 solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jon said:

```
Func<int, int> f = i => i * 2;
Func<int, int> g = i => i * i;
Func<int, int> sum = i => f(i) + g(i);
```

However, if you'd want to create a Sum method for other types than Func<int,int>, you'd have to go with

```
static Func<T, T> Sum<T>(Func<T, T> f, Func<T, T> g)
{
    ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");
    Expression<Func<T, T>> sumExpression =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(
                Expression.Add(
                    Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(f), p),
                    Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(g), p)),
                p);
    return sumExpression.Compile();
}
```

This works for any type T that defines the "+" operator.
Just be careful of the performance penalty you'd get for compiling a lambda expression.

Comment: I think you mean "types other than int".

Comment: Func<int,int> actually; forgot to escape the < >.